# How can I modify an array without destroying an array assigned to it?

Tags: ruby, immutability

Consider the following:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array2 = array1 # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
array2.pop
array2 # => [1, 2, 3]
array1 # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Why is `array1` destroyed when I've only called `pop` on `array2`? Is there a way to `pop` the last value from `array2` and leave `array1` intact so that I get `array1 # => [1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: What does `array1.object_id` and `array2.object_id` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an aliasing issue. Your references point to the same Array object in memory. If your arrays contain simple Integers like those `dup` method do the trick.

```
array2 = array1.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

`array2 = array1.dup`

`array2 = array1.clone` => Your changes effects both arrays

Comment: This is incorrect, or at least misleading. Both `dup` and `clone` produce independent objects, and no later changes to one affect the other. The only two differences between clone and dup is that clone copies the singleton class of the original while dup does not, and cloning a frozen object results in a frozen clone, while a dup is never frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **[Object#dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)** method, but here is one more option FYI:

```
> array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
> array2 = Array.new + array1
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
> array1.object_id
#=> 87422520 
> array2.object_id
#=> 87400390
```